# How to display a specific parameter from json?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I want to display only the parameter `Number` which contains [5,8]. I try the following but does not show any effect.

Any possible answers?

My Json:

```
 {
    "PCol": [{
        "Id": 15,
        "TimeStamp": "2018-02-1",
        "Val": {
            "States": [{
                "Numbers": {
                    "Number": [5, 8]
                },
                "CS": {
                    "ST": "25"
                },
                "Changes": [{
                    "NextTime": 1
                }]
            }]
        }
    }, {
               "Numbers": {
                    "Number": [3, 4]
                 },
               "CS": {
                   "State": "30"
        }
    }]
}
```

Sql Query

```
SELECT K.Number
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON,N'$.PCol') WITH ([Id]  INT  N'$.Id ',
                                     [TimeStamp]  DATETIME N'$.TimeStamp',
                                     [Vals] nvarchar(MAX) N'$.Vals' AS JSON) P
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(P.Vals,N'$.States') WITH (Number  NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.Numbers.Number') K
```

but this displays the column `Number` with `NULL` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but you need another `OPENJSON` to read inside `Numbers`:

```
SELECT x.[value] 
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON,N'$.PCol') 
    WITH ([Id]         INT      N'$.Id ',
          [TimeStamp]  DATETIME N'$.TimeStamp',
          [Val]        nvarchar(MAX)  AS JSON) P
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(P.Val,N'$.States')
    WITH ([Numbers]   nvarchar(MAX)  AS JSON) K
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(K.[Numbers],N'$')  X
```

Result:

[image]

*Edit after OP comment*

Since you have two different structures you can define two select statments each of one reads unoe of the two structures. Then you can put the results together with `union all`:

```
SELECT x.[value] 
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON,N'$.PCol') 
    WITH ([Id]         INT      N'$.Id ',
          [TimeStamp]  DATETIME N'$.TimeStamp',
          [Val]        nvarchar(MAX)  AS JSON) P
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(P.Val,N'$.States')
    WITH ([Numbers]   nvarchar(MAX)  AS JSON) K
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(K.[Numbers],N'$')  X

union all

SELECT x.[value] 
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON,N'$.PCol') 
    WITH ([Numbers]    nvarchar(MAX)  AS JSON,
          [CS]         nvarchar(MAX)  AS JSON) P
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(P.[Numbers],N'$')  X
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks! But, how does it appear only the [5,8] and not [3,4] because they all appear to me

Comment: @chrysa22 Sorry I probably misinterpreted your question. Please see edited answer.